# How to enable AWS RDS loging/logout logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it possible to enable/export RDS user login/logout events to CloudWatch? or are there any other `aws` related tools to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable audit logs for your rds instance, which can capture user logins to the database as well.
You can find more info on that here.
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/advanced-audit-rds-mysql-cloudwatch

[Click here to see example of Audit logs showing CONNECT and DISCONNECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Y72.png)

Comment: Are you sure this captures the login/logout events as well?

Comment: Yes, it does. See the attached screenshot for example. The CONNECT and DISCONNECT logs come on establishing new connection(login), and disconnection(logout).